# Is there way to trap QCMDEXC error in an RPG program other than using MONITOR

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have issued a CL command in a RPGLE program using the QCMDEXC api. Suppose the CL command throws an error. Is there any way of capturing the error without using the MONITOR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "e" code extender

```
    *  Setup QCMDEXEC
    C                   eval      cmdStr = 'CALL PGM(DMACCT001) PARM(REGIONA)'
    C                   eval      cmdLen = %len( cmdStr )
    C* call to QCMDEXC
    C                   callp(e)  command(cmdStr : cmdLen)
    C                   if        %error
    C*    ZZZ    Friendly error handler goes here
    C                   endif

D Command         PR                  ExtPgm('QCMDEXC')
D  CmdStr                    32702    const options(*varsize)
D  CmdLen                       15p 5 const
```